# Memory leak on calling forceLayout

Tags: winjs

I have a *ListView* object which calls the *forceLayout*() method to re-render itself after  its css property *display* is set to none. The reason i'm calling the above method is because I have a master-detail list of many listviews with only one listview visible at a time. After each list item in the master-detail list is selected the corresponding listview will be displayed.

Everytime the *forceLayout*() method is called, the memory increases by around 10mb and is not reclaimed even after the app is suspended. Is it a bug or am I not supposed to be calling the method frequently?

Btw, I'm running Visual Studio RC 2012 on Release Preview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ton of memory leaks were fixed between Release Preview and RTM, so my first suggestion would be to grab the RTM bits and try that.

Failing that, it's probably an issue with your code holding on to references to your data or the rendered DOM elements, but without seeing your code it's hard to say what it might be.

Comment: I'll try the RTM version and see if it fixes the problem. I don't think it's a problem with the code, i've triple checked to see that no circular references are present in it. I would post the code, but it's quite long and not very readable in its present state.

Comment: I installed the RTM version and the memory leaks have gone. I would've reported on the situation earlier, but where I live, the internet's really slow and took me a while to get the RTM downloaded. Thanks.